# How to debug Groovy Commands stored as Text in Intellij Idea

Tags: debugging, groovy, intellij-idea

I have a set of groovy commands stored in the database. These commands are parsed and loaded as a script and then the script is run. Is there a way to debug this script?

I was thinking that I could load all these commands to local file system and associate the script with the stored source file at runtime. Any pointers on how to accomplish this is 
extremely appreciated.

Sample Code:

```
  Script parsedScript = shell.parse(new File("TestScripts.groovy"));// Instead of this line the scripts are loaded from the database.
  parsedScript.run();
```

Intellij Version: 11.4

Answer (score 0):

I know of no way of stepping into TestScripts.groovy when parsed dynamically but why not add the file itself as a source (or add a new module) and run it directly inside IDEA?

[Running and Debugging Groovy Scripts](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/running-and-debugging-groovy-scripts.html)

If you need to regenerate the file from the DB you can create another script to do it before debugging.